# How to use ViewerJS to display PDF (locally, without Webserver)

Tags: javascript, html, browser, file-not-found

I am trying to view/open a PDF file with usage of a local HTML file and ViewerJS
(**without Webserver, i just open the HTML-File with a Browser**).
In short, it doesn't work. PDF is not displayed (Error: **File not found**)

This is my directory structure:
[image]

This is content of folder **ViewerJS**:
[image]

This is my local HTML-File (**PDFViewer.html**), which i try to open in a Browser:

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <iframe src = "/ViewerJS/#../sample.pdf"></iframe>
    <iframe src = "/ViewerJS/#./sample.pdf"></iframe>
    <iframe src = "/ViewerJS/#/sample.pdf"></iframe>
    <iframe src = "/ViewerJS/#sample.pdf"></iframe>

    <iframe src = "ViewerJS/#../sample.pdf"></iframe>
    <iframe src = "ViewerJS/#./sample.pdf"></iframe>
    <iframe src = "ViewerJS/#/sample.pdf"></iframe>
    <iframe src = "ViewerJS/#sample.pdf"></iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```

What i am doing wrong?
What i am missing?

Comment: The instructions on http://viewerjs.org/ specifically ask u to install the js on a webserver!!!!

Comment: Is there no way to use it **without** a webserver?

Comment: If you're comfortable with node.js/npm environment, a colleague showed me server-lite, which takes something like 5mn to set up and allow you to test it.

Comment: I have the same issue have you solved!!

Comment: i have the same issue too... how?